# Как заполнить шаблон email письма пакета nodemailer циклическими данными?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть код формирования шапки и подвала письма и заполнения его переменными.
Однако в письме еще и формируется тело письма состоящее из перечня товаров или услуг.
Подскажите пример на JS как заполнять его в цикле.

```
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
let products =  [{"Товар":"Картофель","Цена":"33"},{"Товар":"Лук","Цена":"31"}]
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(trans);
    await startFetchGetmailTemplate("new_order_admin").then(resp => {
   ﻿   ﻿   ﻿// Из базы данных получаем шаблон HTML с переменными
        mailer.from = "test@test.ru";
        mailer.to = "user@example.com";
        mailer.subject = "тестовое письмо";
        // Как сформировать цикл по товарам с заполнением ?
        // названия переменными из объекта products
        mailer.html = resp.mailer.html;
        transporter.sendMail(mailer).then(result => {
            transporter.close();
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            transporter.close();
        })

    })
```

Comment: Зачем вам цикл? Здесь абсолютно не понятен алгоритм использования ваших продуктов совместно с почтовыми данными. Опишите нормально задачу, что на входе, что на выходе? Откуда взяты продукты? Откуда метод `startFetchGetmailTemplate`, он кастомный или из какого-то движка. Почтовый адрес меняется или нет? И в целом почему вы решили асинхронную операцию выполнять циклом? Я собрался было помочь, но условия очень сумбурно описаны...